# Methods of Geotargeting and optimising for location

Tags: seo, local-seo, geolocation, geotargeting, google-local-search

This is somewhat an SEO question and somewhat a general web developer question.

Our company website is pretty awful, I'm currently redesigning the new one, the problem is they have a directory called regions, which contains page for around 200 different locations around the country, all stuffed to the brim with keywords and useless things.

Some of these pages work and the traffic's good enough to keep a few of them.

Apart from creating a page for everyone again, is there another way of targeting all these locations without having to create a new page for each or is the a more dynamic way to do it?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way regions will be targeted by specific info. I believe there is no shortcut and the only way is to decide you do it via database or static pages. You can still get good SEO rankings with the new website provided you follow the [SEO basics](https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) and have got fresh content.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a lot on what sort of business you're running and what sort of content you could offer for local branches. But, generally speaking, [Google+ Local/Google Places for Business](http://www.google.co.uk/business/placesforbusiness/) is a great tool to use if you want to optimise for local search.

That's the source for local search listings like these:

[image]

You'd do a bulk upload of your locations using their spreadhseet template, and each location can have a link to your site: that could be to a single page, or to individual pages specific to the locale, if branches have (or could have) their own content on your site.